# Find inactive windows vpn name

Tags: vb.net, vpn

How do I find the name of all inactive Windows VPN adapters? I'm working on a VPN app that should list all VPN connections, whether active or inactive. I'm using the NetworkInterface class to list all adapters. It correctly shows the active or inactive Ethernet 2 adapter (used for OpenVPN), and correctly shows the active VPN L2TP connection, but will not list the inactive VPN L2TP adapter name. Are there other (preferably not too obsolete) .Net (or non .Net) classes I could use? I would like to programmaticaly do this, otherwise I could have the option for the user to set the name (I have code to connect, monitor, or disconnect the Windows VPN adapter by name). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found:

```
Public Class VPN


    Public name As String
    Public type As String
    Public status As String
    Public ip As String

End Class

Public Function GetWindowsVPNs() As List(Of VPN)
    Dim vpn_names As String()
    Dim vpns As New RAS
    Dim strVpn As String
    Dim active As Boolean = False
    Dim conIPstr As String = ""
    Dim vpnCheck As New clsVPN
    Dim vpnList As New List(Of VPN)

    vpn_names = vpns.GetConnectionsNames()

    For Each strVpn In vpn_names

        Dim vpn As New VPN
        vpn.name = strVpn
        vpn.type = "Windows VPN"
        active = False
        vpnCheck.ConName = vpn.name
        active = vpnCheck.CheckConnection()

        If active = True Then

            vpn.status = "Active"

            Try

                conIPstr = GetMyIPstr()

            Catch e As Exception

                MessageBox.Show("Error: Function GetConnectionList: Error returning IP Address" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & e.Message)

            End Try

            vpn.ip = conIPstr
        Else
            vpn.status = "Not Active"
            vpn.ip = "No IP Address"
        End If

        vpnList.Add(vpn)

    Next

    Return vpnList

End Function

Private Function GetMyIPstr() As String

    Dim client As New WebClient
    Dim s As String = "No IP Address"
    '// Add a user agent header in case the requested URI contains a query.
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR1.0.3705;)")
    Dim baseurl As String = "http://checkip.dyndns.org/"
    ' with proxy server only:
    Dim proxy As IWebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy()
    proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
    client.Proxy = proxy
    Dim data As Stream
    Try
        data = client.OpenRead(baseurl)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("open url " & ex.Message)
        Exit Function
    End Try
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(data)
    s = reader.ReadToEnd()
    data.Close()
    reader.Close()
    s = s.Replace("<html><head><title>Current IP Check</title></head><body>", "").Replace("</body></html>", "").ToString()
    s = s.Replace("Current IP Address: ", "")
    s = s.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")

    Return s

End Function

Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Public Class clsVPN

    Public Delegate Sub delPing()
    Public Delegate Sub delConnect()
    Public Delegate Sub delIdle()
    Public Delegate Sub delDisconnect()
    Public Delegate Sub delStatus(blnConnected As Boolean)

    Public Event Ping As delPing
    Public Event Con As delConnect
    Public Event Discon As delDisconnect
    Public Event Idle As delIdle
    Public Event StatusChanged As delStatus

    Public strRASPhone As String = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasphone.exe"
    Public strIPAddress As String = ""
    Public strVPNCon As String = ""

    Public blnConnected As Boolean = False

    Dim file As String = "C : \Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk"


    Protected Sub OnStatusChanged(blnConnected As Boolean)

        RaiseEvent StatusChanged(blnConnected)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnDisconnect()

        RaiseEvent Discon()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnPing()

        RaiseEvent Ping()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnIdle()

        RaiseEvent Idle()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnConnect()

        RaiseEvent Con()

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Connected() As Boolean

        Get

            Return blnConnected

        End Get

    End Property


    Public Property ConName() As String

        Get

            Return strVPNCon

        End Get

        Set(strValue As String)

            strVPNCon = strValue

        End Set

    End Property

    Public Function Test() As Boolean

        Dim blnSucceed As Boolean = False

        OnPing()

        Dim p As New Ping()

        If p.Send(strIPAddress).Status = IPStatus.Success Then

            blnSucceed = True

        Else

            blnSucceed = False

        End If

        p = Nothing

        If blnSucceed <> blnConnected Then

            blnConnected = blnSucceed

            OnStatusChanged(blnConnected)

        End If

        OnIdle()

        Return blnSucceed

    End Function

    Public Function Connect() As Boolean

        Dim blnSucceed As Boolean = False
        Dim optionstr As String = "-f " & file & " -d "

        OnConnect()

        'MessageBox.Show("strVPNCon = " )

        'Process.Start(strRASPhone, Convert.ToString(" -f ") & file & Convert.ToString(" -d ") _
        ' & strVPNCon)
        optionstr = ""

        Dim wait As Boolean = True

        ProcessExec(strRASPhone, optionstr & strVPNCon, wait)

        Application.DoEvents()

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

        Application.DoEvents()

        blnSucceed = True

        OnIdle()

        Return blnSucceed

    End Function

    Public Function Disconnect() As Boolean

        Dim blnSucceed As Boolean = False
        Dim optionstr As String = "-h "

        OnDisconnect()

        optionstr = ""

        Dim wait As Boolean = True

        ProcessExec(strRASPhone, optionstr & strVPNCon, wait)

        Application.DoEvents()

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000)

        Application.DoEvents()

        blnSucceed = True

        OnIdle()

        Return blnSucceed

    End Function

    Public Function CheckConnection() As Boolean

        Dim niVPN As NetworkInterface() =
         NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces

        Dim blnExist As Boolean =
         niVPN.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(x) x.Name = ConName)

        If blnExist Then

            'MessageBox.Show("VPN Exists")

        Else

            ' MessageBox.Show("VPN Does Not Exist")

        End If
        Return blnExist

    End Function

    Public Sub ProcessExec(processarg As String, param As String, wait As Boolean)

        ' Start the child process.
        Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
        ' Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.FileName = processarg
        p.Arguments = param
        p.UseShellExecute = True
        p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        Dim proc As Process = Process.Start(p)
        ' Do Not wait for the child process to exit before
        ' reading to the end of its redirected stream.
        If wait = True Then
            proc.WaitForExit()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class


Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class RAS

    Private Const MAX_PATH As Integer = 260 + 1
    Private Const MAX_RAS_ENTRY_NAMES As Integer = 256 + 1

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Public Structure RASENTRYNAME
        Public dwSize As Integer
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=MAX_RAS_ENTRY_NAMES)>
        Public szEntryName As String
        Public dwFlags As Integer
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=MAX_PATH)>
        Public szPhonebook As String
    End Structure

    Private Declare Auto Function RasEnumEntries Lib "rasapi32.dll" (
        ByVal reserved As String,
        ByVal phonebook As String,
        <[In](), Out()> ByVal RasEntries() As RASENTRYNAME,
        ByRef BufferSize As Integer,
        ByRef EntryCount As Integer
    ) As Integer

    Public Function GetConnectionsNames() As String()

        Dim res As New List(Of String)

        Try
            Dim bufferSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(RASENTRYNAME))
            Dim entryCount As Integer = 1
            Dim entryNames(0) As RASENTRYNAME
            Dim rc As Integer

            entryNames(0).dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(RASENTRYNAME))
            rc = RasEnumEntries(Nothing, Nothing, entryNames, bufferSize, entryCount)

            If rc = 0 Then
                ' There was only one entry and it's been filled into the "dummy"
                ' entry that we made before calling RasEnumEntries.
                res.Add(entryNames(0).szEntryName.Trim)

            ElseIf rc = 603 Then
                ' 603 means that there are more entries than we have allocated space for.
                ' So, expand the entryNames array and make sure we fill in the structure size
                ' for every entry in the array!  This is important!!  Without it, you'll get 632 errors!
                ReDim entryNames(entryCount - 1)
                For i As Integer = 0 To entryCount - 1
                    entryNames(i).dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(RASENTRYNAME))
                Next
                rc = RasEnumEntries(Nothing, Nothing, entryNames, bufferSize, entryCount)
                For i As Integer = 0 To entryCount - 1
                    res.Add(entryNames(i).szEntryName.Trim)
                Next

            Else
                ' So if we get here, the call bombed. It would be a good idea to find out why here!
                MsgBox("Error reading RAS connections names, error code:" & rc.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.SystemModal)

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error reading RAS connection names: " & ex.Message.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.SystemModal)

        End Try

        Return res.ToArray

    End Function

End Class
```